# How to make a chmod change permanent

Tags: permissions, printing, scanner

I've recently had to install a brother Printer on a PC with Ubuntu 12.04. To make the scanner work, I’ve had to put this line in terminal:

```
sudo chmod o+wr /dev/bus/usb/00*/*
```

I found this in a forum. What the problem is, is that when I restart my computer that effect just disappears and I have to put it again in terminal.  Is there any way to make that permissions change permanent? 
Thank you so much.

Comment: you should not have to do that at all, try looking at the configuration tool and allowing all users to use the device.

Comment: You should probably add yourself to some group. Does a group like `scanner` exist? Perhaps `lp` will also do.

Comment: And how can i know so?or how can i add me to a group?